# Should I do all blue markers in all Holy Pillar iterations?

Tags: bravely-default

I'm nearing the end-game, at the fourth attempt with the Holy Pillar, I think?

I was under the impression that the sidequests (blue markers) in each Holy Pillar iteration were the same thing (I beat the Merchant guy like three times), so I promptly ignored most of them and simply rushed into the temples.

In this iteration, which begins with Chapter 7, I visited Yulyana for the heck of it. Turns out that I can fight him for his Conjurer asterisk. Then I visited Eternia, and I found Einheria, Khint and Holly there.

So, to my horror, things in this iteration are different from the first world. Were the events in the second, third, etc iterations also different from the first world? In short, my question is:

**SHOULD I have done ALL blue markers in ALL iterations to have a 100% game experience?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 100% game experience, definitely do them. Each time the battle goes slightly different and also the dialog changes (in some cases VERY enjoyably). Also later in the game, the individual enemy groups vary - gradually getting stronger. An example of this is the Eternian legion division in Caldisla - in later iterations, you don't fight just individual commanders or pairs, but you will fight the whole group of commanders in one battle.